# SendGrid 2FA activation/set up link not working

Tags: azure, authentication, sendgrid, multi-factor-authentication

I try to get Sendgrid working with 2nd lowest plan (Essentials 40K - Monthly). However, always when I click link "Open SaaS Account on publisher’s site" in Azure Portal I got site telling following:

> Let's secure your account with Two-Factor Authentication (2FA).
>
> 1. Check your abc****@*****.**** inbox for an email from us.
> 2. Use the link we sent you to set up 2FA.
> 3. Follow the steps to complete setup. It only takes a few minutes.
>
> 2FA protects your account, requiring your password and an
> authentication code when you log in.
>
> Don't see your 2FA email? Resend email.

[Screenshot with above message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SzwK.png)

Yes, I did receive email with link, but every time I click that link got following info:

> Your two-factor authentication set up link expired Two-factor
> authentication links expire after 2 hours. Log in again to have a new
> link sent to your email.

[Screenshot of above message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYT74.png)

That link is clicked immediately within 5 minutes, so do not really know reason for expiration. This loop I can repeat several times with different browsers tested.

So this is happening without possibility to login to Sendgrid even first time. This is the setting up phase.

Anyone with similar case and maybe some solution?

Comment: I ran into the same problem. It worked the first time, but then a day later I got the problem you described. I fixed it by clearing cookies & session storage for sendgrid.com. Then I wasn't asked about 2FA.